# Easing function in PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint, easing

I am looking for the particular easing function that besides standard parameters considers also:

- Accelerate: Percentage of the duration over which acceleration (in part of the animation) should take place.
- Decelerate: Percentage of the duration over which deceleration (out part of the animation) should take place.
- BounceEndIntensity: Percentage of the duration over which BounceEnd (out part of the animation) should take place.

It is not possible to use BounceEndIntensity and Delereate at the same time. This particular easing function is also used for the animations in PowerPoint, but I couldn't find its name in relation with PowerPoint.

Thanx for any ideas!